# User Lock Out (Python/Beatbox)

Tags: apex, soap-api, python, etl

I'm currently implementing a solution using python to bring in information via the Beatbox module for python. http://tomhayden3.com/2013/08/04/salesforce-python/

I got it to write successfully to a CSV, however just about every other time it locks out the account that I am using. I know I have the correct password because its working but the account gets locked out.

Am I missing something on the SF to not have it lock this user out. A user configuration problem, maybe?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What operations are you doing when the user gets locked? How many transactions/how many records are you operating on? What type of org are you using? I believe there's a limit on API calls per day for an org, but I'm not 100% certain. If you're successfully receiving responses from the API, you're not getting locked out because of failed auth attempts

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! A randomly named SQL Management Job was running with incorrect credentials on my dev box. Found the culprit!